# uint32_t assigned to a uint8_t behaivor always same?

Tags: c

```
uint32_t var32;
uint8_t var8;
var32 = 0xFEEDABCD;
var8 = 0;
var8 = var32;
```

Will the above code always (meaning platform dependent such as Windows vs Linux etc) have the following values:

var32 = 0xFEEDABCD

var8 = 0xCD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will. Unsigned integer overflow is well-defined by the standard and it is required to follow modulo-`2^n` semantics.

Comment: Relevant Standard paragraph (C11 and C99): 6.3.1.3/2

Answer (score 0):

Note that the OP is considering "assign uint32_t to int8_t", I think this case actually fits C99 6.3.1.3/3 and the behavior is not well-defined.

> 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.49)
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.